# Watchdog not following the watched process

Tags: linux, apache, systemd

I ran into a problem when trying to build a watchdog for httpd.

The unit part of the systemd service file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
# Bindngs
BindsTo=httpd.service
# Startup
After=httpd.service
```

What happens is that the watchdog restarts on a
systemctl restart httpd

It also follows httpd and stops on a stop, but doesn't start when I start httpd after a stop. Desired behaviour is that the watchdog should follow httpd through all states and restart the device if httpd hangs or stops in an uncontrolled way. That functionality is in place, it's just the systemd stuff that puzzles me.
What should be in the service file to get the watchdog starting and stopping as I want?

Comment: I'm confused about the watchdog functionality. `systemd` is a "watchdog". What you want your watchdog to do that can't already be done directly in `systemd`?

Comment: Are you aware of the `OnFailure=` and `StartLimitLimitAction=` directives documented in `man systemd.unit`? They can already handle triggering a reboot if a service fails. No additional watchdog service is needed.